# Ruby on Rails End of File with SMTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp

Apologies if the answer is out there, but in the many similar posts I've browsed, I haven't found the answer I'm looking for.

I've inherited a Ruby on Rails application, and it recently began failing to send emails. From what I can gather, this is due to an smtp failure.

I want to send emails from "do_not_reply@mydomain.com" using "myaccount@gmail.com" for the SMTP settings.

In **.../config/environments/production.rb** I have

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {                         
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address                        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port                           => 587,             
    :authentication         =>  :plain,                
    :user_name                      => '<myaccount@gmail.com>'
    :password                       => '<mygmailpassword>'      
}
```

and in **.../app/models/** I have a file called **user_notifier.rb** which contains

```
class UserNotifier < ActionMailer::Base
    def signup_notification(user)
        setup_email(user)
        @subject += 'Please activate your new account'
        @body[:url] = "<mydomain.com>:8080/activate/#{user.activation_code}"
    end

    def activation(user)
        setup_email(user)
        @subject += 'Your account has been activated'
        @body[:url] = "<mydomain.com>:8080"
    end

    def reset_notification(user)
        setup_email(user)
        @subject += 'Link to reset your password'
        @body[:url] = "<mydomain.com>:8080/reset_password/#{user.reset_password_code}"
    end

    def login_reminder(user)
        setup_email(user)
        @subject += 'Login Reminder'
        @body[:url] = "<mydomain.com>:8080"
    end

    protected

    def setup_email(user)
        @recipients = "#{user.email}"
        @from = "<do_not_reply@mydomain.com>"
        @subject = "<subject>"
        @sent_on = Time.now
        @body[:user] = user
        bcc ["<myaccount@gmail.com>"]
    end
end
```

All of this code once worked, so I'm not sure what has changed. As I write this, I'm realizing that the sudden failure might have corresponded to some maintenance on the network, so I don't know how that might affect things.

EDIT: Added the entire `UserNotifier` class as requested in the comments

Comment: could you post your complete `UserNotifier` class

Comment: Sure. I just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I actually managed to solve this one myself.

I needed to add the `:domain` option in **.../config/environments/production.rb**

Why it once worked without `:domain` I still don't know, but I'll take just having the functional product.

The working setup was

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {                         
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address                        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port                           => 587,             
    :authentication                 =>  :plain,    
    :domain                         => "gmail.com",
    :user_name                      => '<myaccount@gmail.com>'
    :password                       => '<mygmailpassword>'      
}
```